# Get seconds since midnight in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I want to get the seconds that expired since last midnight. What's the most elegant way in Python?

Comment: What have you tried to do this? Can you share some code with us? (I'm sure the downvotes are just because of this ...)

Comment: Actually I was searching for that question on stackoverflow but could not get an answer. After consulting the python docs I had a solution I liked. To help other people with the same problem I posted my solution as a question & answer. But apparently people don't like that, even though it gets promoted here http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: How about timestamp % 86400?

Comment: @NourChawich clever idea, that should also work if your timezone is UTC

Comment: Why does every answer here require datetime? This is simpler: `t = time.localtime(); since_midnight = t.tm_hour * 3600 + t.tm_min * 60 + t.tm_sec`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It is better to make a single call to a function that returns the current date/time:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
seconds_since_midnight = (now - now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)).total_seconds()
```

Or does

```
datetime.now() - datetime.now()
```

return zero timedelta for anyone here?

Comment: why is it better to use a single call?

Comment: Otherwise you get two concepts of what "now" is.

Comment: @Dirk - because the instant my `now` is created is the instant I want to calculate the number of seconds for. If you take `now` in one line and then the `midnight` in a second line (executed nano/micro/seconds later), your calculations may go wrong. Imagine the midnight occurs in that time.

Comment: Using just "import datetime" avoids masking other datetime methods that might be needed elsewhere in the code.   Sure, you have to use datetime.datetime.now(), but at least it's unambiguous.

Comment: @Dirk - now()-now() is a discrepancy of 17 microseconds (on my laptop), but datetime.now().minute+datetime.now().second/60 - apparently a pretty reasonable calculation - will be off by 59 seconds, about once in 3.5 million attempts.

Comment: `(now - now.normalize()).total_seconds()`
maybe this function is recent, not sure, but I find it a bit more compact :)

Answer (score 28):

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
midnight = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
seconds = (now - midnight).seconds
```

or

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
midnight = datetime.datetime.combine(now.date(), datetime.time())
seconds = (now - midnight).seconds
```

Which to choose is a matter of taste.

Comment: Here. :-) We added it pretty much at the same time, it seems. Although when testing it it turned out I had misspelled things.

Comment: another way to get midnight: [`midnight = datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33276464/4279). btw, any answer that does not use `mktime()` or equiv. fails if there was a DST transition today.

Comment: You can use a correct timezone implementation as well.

Comment: You should use timedelta.total_seconds() instead of .seconds. If there is a nonzero 'days' component, .seconds will not include that, at least as of Python 3.8

Answer (score 4):

I would do it this way:

```
import datetime
import time

today = datetime.date.today()
seconds_since_midnight = time.time() - time.mktime(today.timetuple())
```

Comment: If this is part of your question, it's better to edit your question and add this to your original post as your attempt.

Comment: your answer is the only one that takes the local timezone into account (other answers may produces easily an hour error due to DST transitions). `mktime()` may also fail, see [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279)